Considerations for the placement of the [deck] outer joist to [house] joist connection
Let's start with some terminology: I will be looking for the location to attach the outer joists on a two-story deck - the right one is shown below in the green rectangle.

Let's compare now with the candidate ledgerboard / home attachment areas on my home shown in the picture below as the purple vertical lines labeled A and B where we have two of the house main floor joists:

I am wondering how to choose and then measure the precise location for attaching the right outer joist. My [inexperienced] thoughts on this are:

OptionA:  The right outer joist would be attached below the vertical blue trim to the right of the window right along LocationA.

OptionB:  The right outer joist would be attached sixteen inches further to the right. This gives a wider deck - which has its plusses/minuses that are out of scope. For this exercise I just care about feasibility.


My questions:

Are there any functional differences between the JoistA and JoistB locations [beyond the impact on deck design including the tributary area supported by the beams as well as the beam span].  What I am asking specifically: can any house joist be used as the outer joist attachment and it makes no difference?

What would be the actual precise edge of the deck? Would it be basically the end of the house joist so about 3/4 inch to the right of joist center? Or is further out and if so how much? What comes into play for the exact location of the outer edge of the rim joist? I need that for site plans and for calculating tributary area.

Are there any further considerations for the rim joist location either functionally or aesthetically?


